# Pasted vector from illustrator into Indesign. Change frame type

Tags: adobe-indesign

Every object I've pasted from Illustrator into Indesign won't let me crop the frame without scaling the object. Meaning every object going off page I want to trim to the page frame just changes scale, I can't simply trim the frame like a standard object without the scake changing. Meaning the frame is dashed rather then a clean line. I know it sounds complex but I'm still learning and really want to change the frame type.

Comment: If you're still learning it might be a good time to understand its good practice to use your AI artwork as external links instead of copy pasting to Indesign. This is the normal work flow and it will save you time in the future as you might get to deal with more complex documents.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your graphic from Illustrator.

Go to InDesign and select the rectangle you want to paste the graphic into.

Go to Edit -> Paste -> Paste Into (CTRL/CMD + Alt + V)